# casting parent to child - strange behavior in array

Tags: java, arrays, casting, polymorphism, parent-child

I thought you can't cast `Parent` to `Child`, and can only cast `Child` to `Parent`. Or at least if you did, you wouldn't be allowed to access the child's functions.

Then I see that Java will allow me to explicitly cast parent to child:

```
a=(B)a;
```

but will not allow

```
bArray[0]=a
```

or

```
a.testB();
```

Yet this is ok:

```
bArray[1]=(B)a;
```

and so is this:

```
bArray[1].testB();
```

Can someone please explain what's going on here!? How can a parent class be given functions of a child class? And why does the first attempt at placing a into the array not work, but the second attempt does? Shouldn't it be the same?

```
class A {
    public void testA() {
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public void testB() {
    }
}

public class polymorphicObjects {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B bArray[] = new B[5];      
        A a = new A();
        A ab = new B();

        a = (B)a; //didnt think you could do this
        bArray[0] = a; //but if I can the why doesnt this work?
        a.testB();  //or this
        bArray[1] =(B)a; //but this does work
        bArray[1].testB(); //and so does this!? 
    }
}
```

Comment: **//why doesnt this work?** - Because you declared `a` as beeing of type A. it doesn't matter if you do. `A a = (B) new A();`. The variable `a` will still be of type `A` because thats how you defined it. Anyway. I'm sure actually none of this works and if you try to run it you will just get a ClassCastException. Just because it compiles doens't mean it works.

Comment: Ha yes class cast exception. Im studying for OCJA and theyve been throwing weird stuff at me. Didn't think to hit compile. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does running `bArray[1].testB();` actually work? That should throw a ClassCastException at least. Adding a print statement inside the testB() method should help with that.

So in this, you're saying `a = (B)a;` which is very explicitly casting a to type B, but it doesn't actually mean anything.

With that in mind, this doesn't work in the first line, `bArray[0] = a;` because it's no longer explicitly cast, so the compiler will complain that you're giving a type that doesn't match.

In the subsequent line `bArray[1] = (B)a;` you are explicitly telling the compiler that a is of type B, so it won't bark at you... although the call to the method testB() should fail at runtime.

Comment: You are right- class cast exception. I didn't think to compile it. Ive been studying for OCJA and at this point was just relying on Eclipse to tell me by the red line. Guess it can't catch everything prior to compile. Thanks!

Comment: If you wouldn't mind, I'd appreciate it if you accepted my answer :) I've only just now started to give back to the community I've depended on throughout my college career.

Comment: I did but I don't have enough reputation on the Java Stackoverflow for my vote to count :/ . Im mainly just a lurker here haha. I will come back and up vote it again when I have enough rep!

Comment: Well, you still have to accept an answer since you asked it. Not the vote, but accepting the answer to your question

Answer (score 1):

In Java, casting has a very specific meaning (different from the C language, e.g.). You have to distinguish what class your object actually has, and what the compiler thinks about the class of some expression.

Casting doesn't change the actual object class, but only what the compiler thinks about the class of the expression.

Let's walk through your code:

`new A()` will always give you an object of class A, and the compiler knows that.

You store that into a reference variable `a`, declared to be of class A, so from the declaration (not the `new A()` expression) the compiler knows that variable `a` has class A (allowing subclasses as well).

With the cast expression `(B) a` you don't change anything about the object that's stored in `a`, just assert to the compiler that you, as the developer, know that the object stored in `a` is of type B (which is not true, in your case, it's an A, not a B). The compiler isn't intelligent enough to see that, so he treats the expression `(B) a` as valid and of class B. He allows you to cast from A to B because B is a subclass of A, so a variable of class A might perfectly well contain an object of class B (e.g. `A a = new B();` would be perfectly OK). At runtime, the JVM will check for the actual object class and raise a ClassCastException as it finds out that it's an A not coming from subclass B.

With `a = (B) a;` you store your same object back into the same variable where it came from.

You ask about `bArray[0] = a;` This doesn't compile because for the compiler, `a` contains an object of class A, and the array needs a B. `bArray[1] = (B) a;` will compile, but throw a ClassCastException when run as long as the variable still contains the same object of class A.

And `bArray[1].testB();` compiles because the compiler knows that in the `bArray` all elements are of class B, and class B has this method. As trying to store an object which isn't of class B into `bArray` won't work (either at compile-time `bArray[0] = a;` or at run-time `bArray[1] = (B) a;`), calling the testB() method is safe.

Comment: This is a great explanation. Thanks. I will come back and up vote this answer too when I have enough reputation for it to matter.